# JQuery Function problem. Adding too many classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with this function.  The problem is with TD index 2, as commented below.  The HTML in each iteration is correct, but I cannot figure out why it is adding extra classes?  The class should be the same as the HTML.

1st iteration:
  HTML: A
  CLASS: A

2nd iteration:
  HTML: B
  CLASS: A B

3rd iteration:
  HTML: C
  CLASS: A B C

4th iteration:
  HTML: A
  CLASS: A B C

5th iteration:
  HTML: B
  CLASS: A B C

6th iteration:
  HTML: C
  CLASS: A B C

```
function formatTable(){
    count=1;
    phase="";
    var phase13 = $('input[name=voltage]:checked').attr("phase");
    var cClass =  $('input[name=voltage]:checked').attr("cClass");

    $tableID.find('tbody tr').each(function(idx){
        $(this).children().eq(1).html(count++);

        switch (phase13){
            case "1":
                if ((count) % 4 == 0) {
                    phase = "B";
                } else {
                    phase = "A";
                }
                break;
            case "3":
            default:
                if ((count+1) % 3 == 0){
                    phase="A";
                } else {
                    if (count % 3 == 0){
                        phase="C";
                    } else {
                        phase="B";
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        $(this).children().eq(2).html(phase).addClass(cClass).addClass(phase);  // This sets HTML to A, B or C, but after the 3rd iteration adds Class A, B and C.
        $(this).children().eq(3).html(count++);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're never removing the old `phase` class, so the new class is simply being added to the list. Add `removeClass('A B C')` before adding the new phase class:

```
$(this).children().eq(2).html(phase).addClass(cClass).removeClass('A B C').addClass(phase);
```

By using `removeClass('A B C')` you don't have to worry about figuring out which phase class was currently set on the element, as this will remove them all.